# Something wrong with shadow in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

[image][image]
How can I change my shadow to normal?

Source of spotlight and renderer:

```
        spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
        spotLight.position.set(0, room.height, 0);
        spotLight.castShadow = true;
        spotLight.shadowMapWidth = 8192; // default is 512
        spotLight.shadowMapHeight = 8192; // default is 512
        scene.add(spotLight);

        renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
        renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
        renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
        renderer.shadowCameraNear = 0.1;
        renderer.shadowCameraFar = camera.far;
        renderer.shadowCameraFov = 45;
        renderer.shadowMapBias = 1;
        renderer.shadowMapDarkness = 0.5;
        renderer.shadowMapWidth = 8192;
        renderer.shadowMapHeight = 8192;
        renderer.sortObjects = false
```

Object is casting and receiving the shadow.

Comment: It is not clear. do you want the object to receive shadow? where is the code where you tell the object to cast shadows?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with `Something wrong with shadow...`? For me it looks normal? How should it look like?

Comment: do you mean, that the shadow looks bigger than the object?

Comment: Shadow on the ground is normal. But shadow on the bottom of object is not.

Comment: _mesh.castShadow = true;
_mesh.receiveShadow = true;

Comment: I have added one more img

Comment: Why is `bias` 1? Read about [bias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799206/stripped-shadows-on-collada-objects/30803087#30803087) here.