# Threejs Shadows not rendering

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I have looked over all the other shadow issues on here, and none of them seemed relevant to mine, or I just overlooked it about 10 times.

https://gist.github.com/Sinistralis/58249d2f9aefa8f08a7d

I would make a fiddle for this, but the version they host seems incompatible with either my code or the current version of chrome. I could not get it to work even after changing .merge and BoxGeometry back to GeometryUtils and CudeGeometry respectively.

Basically, I am getting 0 shadows using threejs v .71

I have all the cast booleans set, the scene is within my shadowmap, and I am using a correct light type. Why am I not getting shadows?

Comment: maybe increase your shadowCameraFar (your scene looks kinda large for it to be just 1300) and set a shadowCameraNear.

Comment: Scene is large for 1300 yes, but the light was only at a Z level of 1000. This likely isn't a good looking example, but this code is simply for learning purposes for the moment. I need to break out the code into something more readable and maintainable before I consider making something serious with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to be very helpful to other users, unfortunately...

The proper spelling is *receive*.

```
floor.receiveShadow = true;
city.receiveShadow = true;
```

Also, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799206/stripped-shadows-on-collada-objects/30803087#30803087) about self-shadowing artifacts.

three.js r.71

Comment: I'll see myself out -_-